# Study the ring $\mathbb {Z} \left[ -\frac{1}{2}+i \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \right]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, roots

> Let $\varepsilon = - \frac{1}{2}+ i \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}, \varepsilon^3=1$. Now consider the set $\mathbb{Z}[\varepsilon] = \left\{ a + b \varepsilon \mid (a, b) \in \mathbb{Z}^2 \right\} \subseteq \mathbb{C}$. We take for granted that this set is in fact a commutative ring (and an integral domain). Find the elements of the group $(U(\mathbb{Z}[\varepsilon]), \cdot)$, where $U(\mathbb{Z}[\varepsilon]) = \left\{ x \in \mathbb{Z}[\varepsilon] \mid \exists y \in \mathbb{Z}[\varepsilon]\colon xy=1 \right\}$. Prove that $\mathbb{Z}[\varepsilon]$ is a Euclidean domain and find all $p \in \mathbb{Z}[\varepsilon]$ such that the equation $x^2+px+1=0$ has at least one solution.

My approach: 
Assume that the polynomial $x^2+px+1=0$ has a root, let's call it $a$. By Bezout's Theorem $x^2+px+1=(x-a)(x-b)$, for some $b \in \mathbb{Z}[\varepsilon]$. So $x^2+px+q=x^2-(a+b)x+ab$. So $a$ and $b$ must be invertible and $p$ can take the values of all the possible sums of invertible elements.

However, I cannot find the set $U(\mathbb{Z}[\varepsilon])$. I have tried using the same approach as with the gaussian integers, to consider the norm $N\colon \mathbb{Z}[\varepsilon] \to \mathbb{N}, \, N(a+b\varepsilon)=a^2+b^2$. And if $a+b\varepsilon$ divides $c+d\varepsilon$ then $N(a+b\varepsilon)$ divides $N(c+d\varepsilon)$, although I don't think $N(xy)=N(x)N(y)$. My intuition says that $U(\mathbb{Z}[\varepsilon])= \left\{ 1, -1, \varepsilon, -\varepsilon, \varepsilon^2, -\varepsilon^2 \right\}$, but I do not know how to formalize this. Any help would be gladly appreciated.

Comment: Look up [tag:eisenstein-integers].  Often what you denoted $\varepsilon$ is denoted $\omega$

Comment: you have $a + b \varepsilon \in \mathbb C$   What is the complex conjugate of $a + b \varepsilon \; ? \; \; $

Comment: Your proposed norm isn't multiplicative -- for example, $(1 + \varepsilon)^2 = \varepsilon$ but with your formula $N(1 + \varepsilon) = 2, N(\varepsilon) = 1$.

Comment: @WillJagy the conjugate of $\epsilon$ is just $-1-\epsilon$

Comment: For the units see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2624480/units-of-mathbbz-omega-where-omega-frac12-1-sqrta-a0?rq=1), and for units and Euclidean domain see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/164656/uniqueness-units-of-the-eisenstein-integers).